# User history type selection z-index needs to be increased

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, moderator-tools, users

In the moderator 'user history' view, there's a popup box to select what type of history events to view. It's supposed to pop up *above* everything else, but only pops up above the history entries. It still lies behind the user flair:

[image]

While we're at it, can we increase the padding on red-background events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fixed now, it'll be live after our next production build.